# document.form.action not working in IE but working in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I've the following GET with an input, with an auxiliary JS function that appends me some more content on the URL.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function injectQuerySentence() {
        var userInput = document.getElementById("userInputBox").value;
        document.myformName.action += '#order=relevance&q=' + userInput;
    }
</script>

<form name='myformName' method="GET" onsubmit="injectQuerySentence()" >
    <input type="hidden" name="option" value="es" />
    <input type="hidden" name="view" value="search" />
    <input id="userInputBox"class="searchbox" type="textbox"/>
</form>
```

If I put the string `hello` on the form and push enter, I get the following URL:

```
https://mywebsite?option=es&view=search#order=relevance&q=hello&
```

Everything works ok in Chrome and Firefox but it's not working on Internet Explorer. With IE I'm just getting this url:

```
https://mywebsite?option=es&view=search
```

How can I make it work in IE?

**EDIT:** I don't see any error on the ES console.

Comment: the query parameters are automatically appended to the action uri. The common design pattern is to use a hidden input element to pass the hash tokens as a query parameter.eg. <input type="hidden" name="order" value="relevance"/>

Comment: @RobParsons That patter (which I use for `option` and `view`) appends a `&` to the URL. As you can see I would like to append `#order=relevance&q=whatever` to the URL. That's why I'm appending it via Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This is an error (or at best "quirk") in IE's handling of form.action

based on your code, you can do this instead:

```
    document.myformName.action = window.location.href + '#order=relevance&q=' + userInput;
```

which would change the url in  the same way for IE.